# Can anyone please tell me how to activate loopback on Wireshark?

Tags: sockets, http, localhost, wireshark

I have a local host webserver c++ code which runs on port 8080 on windows 10.
My first task is to test http requests and responses, and it's done properly with Postman. 
But I have another task which is to capture those requests and responses via Wireshark(No other packet sniffing application). 
Now, as far as I know it's no possible doing it unless one installs a loopback adapter, so I did it. But Wireshark still doesn't capture packets from and to port 8080. 
Can sombedy please tell me what other configurations need to be done so it will be possible?

Answer (score 2):

Probably your best option is to install and use [Npcap](https://nmap.org/npcap/) instead of [WinPcap](https://www.winpcap.org/).  Be sure to install npcap's loopback adapter and capture on that interface and not on the Microsoft Loopback Adapter interface.

Another very good and simple option (if you're not required to use Wireshark) is to use [RawCap](https://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap) instead of [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

Refer to the Wireshark [Loopback capture setup](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback) wiki page for more details.

Comment: Thanks very much!